# Why do I get duplicated logging messages?

Tags: python, logging

I have a script which imports a logging module (based on `logging`) and another module (which in turn imports the same logging module as the main one -- to have consistent logging accorss the scripts and modules).

Everything works fine except that I get duplicated messages. Below are the scripts stripped down to the problematic part:

**The main script**. It sets a logging handler, used in a method of his

```
# the main script
# it is the one started

import dslogger
import mytestmodule

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = dslogger.DSLogger().rootLogger

    def dosomething(self):
        self.log.debug("hello from dosomething")

mytestmodule.MyTestModule()
MyClass().dosomething()
```

**The `mytestmodule`**. Here stripped down to `__init__`:

```
# mytestmodule.py

import dslogger

class MyTestModule():
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = dslogger.DSLogger().rootLogger
        self.log.debug("hello from mytestmodule")
```

**`dslogger.py`, the logging module**:

```
import logging

class DSLogger():
    def __init__(self):
        logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(funcName)s] [%(levelname)s]  %(message)s")
        self.rootLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
        self.rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
```

When running the main script I get:

```
2014-11-04 08:56:59,637 [__init__] [DEBUG]  hello from mytestmodule
2014-11-04 08:56:59,637 [dosomething] [DEBUG]  hello from dosomething
2014-11-04 08:56:59,637 [dosomething] [DEBUG]  hello from dosomething
```

The second and third line are duplicated, even though they are generated by the `dosomething()` method which is called only once, from the main script. Why is it so?

Comment: Can you also provide the main script?

Comment: @badc0re: it is the first one

Comment: Oh sorry i kind of missed it :D

Comment: with this `dslogger.DSLogger().rootLogger` you are creating a new instance each time, why are you not using  `logging.getLogger("DSLogger")` in each class for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that you're adding two `StreamHandler`s to the same logger.

You initialize `DSLogger()` twice. Each time you initialize it, you call `self.rootLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. But this *does not* get you two different logger instances, since they are called with same `__name__`:

```
import logging
x = logging.getLogger('x')
id(x)
Out[42]: 173704528L

y = logging.getLogger('x')
id(y)
Out[44]: 173704528L
```

So when you call `self.log.debug("hello from mytestmodule")`, this is after `DSLogger()` was initalized once, and thus only one `StreamHandler` was added to that logger. But when you initialize `MyClass`, another one is added, and thus the logger now has two `StreamHandler`s, and every log message is printed twice.

Comment: Thank you, it is now clear. I thought that when you instantiate  objects, they are always independent. I will rewrite `DSLogger`to accept in `__init__` a parameter, which I will pass upon initiating the logging in the main script and the modules (I will pass `__name__`)

Comment: @WoJ Note that you're not instantiating self.rootLogger. you're calling a 'get' function.

Comment: Ahhhhh right! Now I really understand. I will have to think harder on the consequences of using the `get` call as I do it now (with the modifications from my comment above) vs. actually instantiating a logger object via `log = dslogger.DSLogger()` and adding `return rootLogger` to `__init__` in `DSLogger()`