# python logger prints everything twice

Tags: python, python-logging

I try using this [openshift-restclient-python library](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-python). My custom Logger prints everything twice after I run into this [bug](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-python/issues/430).

modules/logging/Logging.py

```
import logging
class CustomLogger:
    logger=None
    def __init__(self):
        if (CustomLogger.logger==None):
            logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
            logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
            stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)
            CustomLogger.logger=logger

    def getLogger(self):
    return CustomLogger.logger

logger = CustomLogger().getLogger()
```

This ist my main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from modules.logging.Logging import logger
from kubernetes import client, config
from openshift.dynamic import DynamicClient
from openshift.helper.userpassauth import OCPLoginConfiguration
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
apihost = 'myhost'
username = 'myuser'
password = 'insecure'
ca_cert = '/path/to/cert'
kubeConfig = OCPLoginConfiguration(ocp_username=username, ocp_password=password)
kubeConfig.host = apihost
kubeConfig.verify_ssl = False
kubeConfig.ssl_ca_cert = ca_cert
kubeConfig.get_token()
k8s_client = client.ApiClient(kubeConfig)
logger.warning("this is printed once")
dyn_client = DynamicClient(k8s_client)
logger.warning("this is printed twice")
v1_projects = dyn_client.resources.get(api_version='project.openshift.io/v1', kind='Project')
project_list = v1_projects.get()
sys.exit(0)
```

executing the main.py I get the following output

```
this is printed once
ERROR:root:load cache error: ResourceList.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'base_resource_lookup'
this is printed twice
WARNING:modules.logging.Logging:this is printed twice
```

If I do not use my custom logger but a simple configuration as below in main.py then everything is printed once.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59785565/python-logger-prints-line-twice-without-configure-logging) so I also tried removing any handler but the only handler is the one that contains my customization, so I end up with a basic logger.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

**EDIT:**
There is an easier way reproducing the issue.
I still have my custom logger as posted before but my main.py now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from modules.logging.Logging import logger
import logging
print(logger.handlers)
print("number handlers: " +str(len(logger.handlers)))
logger.warning("this is printed once")
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger.warning("this is printed twice")
print("number handlers: " +str(len(logger.handlers)))
for h in logger.handlers:
logger.removeHandler(h)
print("number handlers: " +str(len(logger.handlers)))
logger.warning("still get printed")
sys.exit(0)
```

the output:

```
[<StreamHandler <stderr> (DEBUG)>]
number handlers: 1
this is printed once
this is printed twice
WARNING:modules.logging.Logging:this is printed twice
number handlers: 1
number handlers: 0
WARNING:modules.logging.Logging:still get printed
```

The code `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` doesn't add another handler but cause everything to be logged. I actually only want the customized logs printed by the streamingHandler. How can I revert what is done by `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get duplicated logging messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730233/why-do-i-get-duplicated-logging-messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it that way:

```
class CustomLogger:
      logger=None
      def __init__(self):
          if (CustomLogger.logger==None):
              logging.basicConfig(filename='/dev/null', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
              logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
              logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
              fmt = '%(asctime)s | %(message)s'
              stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
              stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
              stdout_handler.setFormatter(CustomFormatter(fmt))
              logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)
              CustomLogger.logger=logger

    def getLogger(self):
        return CustomLogger.logger

logger = CustomLogger().getLogger()
```

It seems that the library I am using at some place logs to the RootLogger. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32341761/10285726) logging.basicConfig() is a constructor of a streamHandler that connects to the RootLogger.

If I use `logger = logging.getLogger('root')` instead of `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` then everything is printed once. However, in that case everything the library logs on DEBUG-Level is printed to the terminal.

The line `logging.basicConfig(filename='/dev/null', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')` causes that everything logged by the root logger is printed to /dev/null.

Answer (score 0):

Please try remove this peace of code from class `CustomLogger`

```
stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)
```

---

btw i was struggling with the same. **Found answers using search on this website.**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26730545/15637940

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70876179/15637940

*and a lot more answered questions...*

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried removing the handler. As I wrote I have found a similar answer so I also tried removing any handler but the only handler is the one that contains my customization, so I end up with a basic logger that has no customizing.